# Are changes to an atomic variable with std::memory_order_relaxed visible to another thread with the Qt's signal-slot mechanism?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

In C++/Qt, when modifying an atomic variable with std::memory_order_relaxed before emitting a signal, are the changes guaranteed to be visible to a slot connected to this signal with Qt::QueuedConnection?

For example, suppose that one thread stores a new value to an atomic variable with the relaxed memory order and then emits the `variableChanged()` signal.

```
atomic_variable.store(new_value, std::memory_order_relaxed);
emit variableChanged();
```

And there is the `handleVariable()` slot that handles the signal and is called in another thread.

```
// connected to variableChanged()
void handleVariable()
{
  const auto v = atomic_variable.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  // Will this thread get the new value or the old?
}
```

Comment: Changes in `std::atomic` is always visible in transactional order. Memory order is related to other variables, not atomic itself.

Comment: @Slava I suppose that is where "_and then emits the variableChanged() signal._" comes in. If the signal mechanism doesn't provide synchronization guarantees, then there is no guarantee that the handler of the signal will see the atomic change. There is a single global modification order for the atomic, but it doesn't need to be consistent with the signal mechanism's ordering, although I guess it wouldn't be very useful if it doesn't make a synchronization guarantee.

Comment: @user17732522 not sure what "synchronization guarantees" means. If code changes atomic variable and then emits signal, reading thread will see changed value reading from the same atomic, there is no another way it would happen, otherwise `std::atomic` is fundamentally broken. If thread modifying atomic and thread emitting signal are different then this is completely different story.

Comment: @Slava Suppose for example emit was just a store to an atomic and the event loop in the thread for `handleVariable` was just a loop looking for changes in that value. If both of these load and store were also relaxed, then there would not be any happen-before relationship between the invocation of `handleVariable` and `atomic_variable.store`, so `handleVariable` may see the old value of `atomic_variable` (e.g. the compiler may reorder the store and emit). Of course that wouldn't make sense as behavior for the signal mechanism. It should be using some stronger ordering or synchronization.

Comment: @user17732522 emit does not store, emit notifies Qt system that signal has to be raised. So if emit called after `atomic_variable.store` from the same thread then signal handler will see `atomic_variable` after store happened period. Again memory relaxed is not related to `atomic_variable` itself, atomic access is always transactional.

Comment: @Slava "So if emit called after atomic_variable.store from the same thread then signal handler will see atomic_variable after store happened": Only if emit includes some operation that enforces a _synchronizes-with_ relationship, e.g. a release operation or a mutex lock or something of that kind. If none exists, then the compiler can reorder the store after the emit. And if a synchronizes-with relationship exists, then it also doesn't actually matter whether `atomic_variable` is atomic. But as I said, I would expect emit to include such a synchronization, otherwise it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: I asked ChatGPT the same question, and it said "In this case, the handleVariable() slot may read the old value of the atomic variable instead of the new value, because the slot's execution is deferred until a later time and may occur before the changes to the atomic variable are propagated to the memory visible to the receiving thread. To ensure that the changes made to the atomic variable are visible, you can use an explicit synchronization mechanism, such as a mutex or a memory barrier, to ensure that the changes to the atomic variable are fully propagated before emitting the signal"

Comment: @user17732522 "If none exists, then the compiler can reorder the store after the emit." are we talking about `std::atomic`? No it cannot, otherwise what is the point of using `std::atomic` vs regular variable?

Comment: @Alex not sure if ChatGPT would be an expert here. Again if `std::atomic`  update happened before `emit` **in the same thread** then there is no way that value will not propagate to another thread, as signal handling will not happen before emit.

Comment: Practically speaking, there's a ton of synchronization involved in delivering a Qt signal to another thread. Like thread-safe producer-consumer queues, with mutexes and such. Qt signals are routinely used to notify other threads of changes to non-atomic variables, so there's got to be sufficient memory barriers to make that work.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik even if it would not in case of `std::atomic` it cannot work another way - store operation must be sequenced before `emit` (whataver it does under the hood). Signal handling cannot happen before emit, so there is no way that signal handling happens before `store` finishes.

Comment: As for memory order, this is common misunderstanding, it does not affect `std::atomic` itself. Let's say we have this `int a =  0, b = 0; std::atomic<int> c = 0;` then code `a=1;b=2;c=3;` memory order may affect if you see `b==2` before `a==1` or not, but you will see `c==3` no matter what if you read happens after store.

Comment: @Slava If you have `std::atomic<int> a = 0; std::atomic<int> b = 0;`, then `a.store(1, memory_order_relaxed); b.store(1, memory_order_relaxed);` and `int x = b.load(memory_order_relaxed); int y = a.load(memory_order_relaxed); assert(!(x == 1 && y == 0));` in two threads, assert is possible. Imagine `a` represents OP's atomic and `b` the Qt signalling. The modification order of each atomic is consistent with sequencing in threads individually, but there does not need to be a combined total modification order of all atomics for threads to agree upon. That requires seq_cst ordering in general.

Comment: The point of relaxed atomics is that they do not cause data races when accessed without synchronization and that they have _individually_ a consistent modification order that all threads agree upon and that is consistent with sequencing in the threads.

Comment: @user17732522 "Imagine a represents OP's atomic and b the Qt signalling." this is not the case. Lets say I have code `atomic_var.store( 123 ); someFunctionCall();` when I am inside function `someFunctionCall()` `atomic_var.store( 123 );` is done, so if I read it or notify another thread or whatever store is done.

Comment: @user17732522 let's make it little more formal: `atomic_var.store(123); someFunc();` compiler may not know what can happen inside `someFunc()` so it must assume that `atomic_var.load()` or another operation on it happens inside, so it **must** finish all side effects of `atomic_var.store(123);` before `someFunc()` called. Agree? Which implies that when emit called and it somehow notifies main Qt loop that `store()` must be finished. And signal handling cannot run before `someFunc()` is called.

Comment: @Slava You are assuming that the compiler can't see inside `someFunc()`, but that's not guaranteed. It may see the whole emit mechanism. If it is guaranteed that the compiler can't (e.g. because the emit mechanism is in a shared library with non-visible definitions in the main program), then that itself is a synchronization mechanism.

Comment: @user17732522 even if it can see, evaluation of atomic store is sequenced before and I believe for atomic vars sequenced means it must finish storing before `someFunc()` starts, no matter if compiler can see inside or not. Otherwise there is not difference btw atomic and non atomic variable.

Comment: @Slava The only difference between relaxed atomics and non-atomics is that a relaxed store to an atomic will either be completely visible or not visible at all. It is not possible to observe one byte in the old state and one byte in the new one, nor is possible to observe different modification orders in multiple threads. In other words, there are no data races. Nothing else is really different. But it does not imply any ordering with anything else.

Comment: "Sequenced-before" is a property that is relevant only in a single thread. If the behavior in the thread in which the two expressions are sequenced isn't dependent on their ordering, then the compiler does not need to emit them to machine code in the order of their sequenced-before relationship. Successive statements in a thread are always sequenced. That would make most compiler optimizations impossible. It does not (by itself) impose anything on visibility from other threads or ordering of emitted instructions.

Comment: "Sequenced-before" is a property that is relevant only in a single thread. - yes and atomic store and emit function in a single thread indeed.